# DockPanel Suite - Move DockContent from one Dock Panel to another

Tags: dockpanel-suite

I have a C# .NET application that opens multiple windows with a DockPanel control. I would like to be able to drag a DockContent object from one DockPanel to one in another form. Has anyone figured out how to accomplish this? Right now you can only drag it back into the DockPanel that is was originally added to.